# Need meaning of below debug message while authenticating via LDAP

Tags: ldap, ambari

```
Got Ldap context on server
```

This is a part of Debug message.Was the first bind successful?

```
2X Mar 201X 15:36:36,880 DEBUG [ambari-client-thread-37] FilterBasedLdapUserSearch:115 - Searching for user 'XXXX', with user search [ searchFilter: '(&(sAMAccountName={0})(objectClass=posixAccount))', searchBase: '', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
2X Mar 201X 15:36:36,917 DEBUG [ambari-client-thread-37] AbstractContextSource:349 - Got Ldap context on server 'ldap://rXXX92.corp.XXX.com:389/DC=corp,DC=XXX,DC=com'
2X Mar 201X 15:36:36,929 DEBUG [ambari-client-thread-37] DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher:94 - No event was found for the exception org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.InvalidUsernamePasswordCombinationException
2X Mar 201X 15:36:36,929 DEBUG [ambari-client-thread-37] AmbariBasicAuthenticationFilter:185 - Authentication request for failed: org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.InvalidUsernamePasswordCombinationException: Unable to sign in. Invalid username/password combination.
```

Answer (score 0):

No. 
Looks like LDAP credentials are wrong: "Unable to sign in. Invalid username/password combination"